# MySQL Error: You can't specify target table 'users_words' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

Please have a look at my MySQL clause.

```
UPDATE `users_words` SET `priority` = (SELECT MAX(`priority`)+1 FROM `users_words`) where `userid` = 89 AND `wordid`="agree"
```

Here I am going to update the `priority` field by adding 1 to the existing maximum `priority` field value. But I am getting the error `You can't specify target table 'users_words' for update in FROM clause`.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your subquery in another `SELECT` :

```
UPDATE `users_words` 
SET `priority` = (SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT MAX(`priority`)+1 FROM `users_words`) x) 
WHERE `userid` = 89 AND `wordid`="agree"
```

Comment: Perfect trick! awesome!